# Unable to reduce the size of the boxes in daterangeInput in rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

The orginal code has lot of parameter, hence i am showing a sample snippet. I tried using div but still unable to reduce the box sizes . The boxes are basically which contains the dates.

```
dateRangeInput("date", "Date range:",
                       start  = "2013-05-15",
                       end    = "2013-10-01",
                       min    = "2013-05-15",
                       max    = "2013-10-01",
                       format = "dd/mm/yy",
                       separator = " - ")
```

Comment: [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/dateRangeInput.html) here is the help page for `dateRangeInput()` - it looks like there is an argument `width = ` that controls the size.